# Dataframe shows less rows that are in file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create dataframe with pandas that consists a txt file of 12000 rows and 3 columns. Whenever i try to `read_csv` it says that dataframe is 1998x3. I tried `header=None` but still does not show right dimensions. There is no header in dataset, just raw data. example first row in txt: 1.03, 3.01, 2.01
What can i do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. For debugging help, you'll need to make a [mre]. From what you've said, it's possible you're simply reading the wrong file. Working through the problem should help catch any mistakes like that.

Comment: Most likely due to some corrupted cell. You need to see what's causing a problem; try to use combination of `error_bad_lines=False` and `warn_bad_lines=True`

Comment: Why don't you show us the first few lines of the file?